# sending request to wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

am trying to send a request to the identity server but don't know how to do it.  I know that identity server can help you test your policy by generating a request for you within the identity server but I don't know how to do this outside the identity server.  So my question is how do I sent requests to identity server in order to have it check the request against the policy and return to me a result.  I have tried the blog at http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2011/12/entitlement-service-xacml-pdp-as-web.html and it is not working.  thank you

Comment: why you need to invoke the identity server? what is the functionality you expect from that.

Comment: hello, I want identity server to act as an entitlement engine but am having trouble sending requests to it, I have already uploaded the policies onto the identity server, I now need to know how to send a request to the Identity server, have it evaluate the request and send back a decision.  Identity server lets you test your policy by providing means to create a request but I would like to send a request from my computer to the Identity server. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in the blogpost and could get it worked with the following settings with WSO2 Identity Server 4.1.0 in localhost. Don't forget to give correct path to the wso2carbon.jks.

```
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis2.client.Options;
import org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.AuthenticationAdminStub;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub.EntitlementServiceStub;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui.client.EntitlementServiceClient;

public class EntitlementClient {

private static String serverUrl = "https://localhost:9443/services/";

private AuthenticationAdminStub authstub = null;
private static ConfigurationContext ctx;
private static String authCookie = null;
private static EntitlementServiceClient entitlementServiceClient;
private static EntitlementServiceStub stub;
//sample XACML request captured from TryIt tool of IdentityServer.  
private static String sampleRequest = "<Request xmlns=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:context:schema:os\"\n" +
        "         xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n" +
        "    <Resource>\n" +
        "        <Attribute AttributeId=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id\"\n" +
        "                   DataType=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string\">\n" +
        "            <AttributeValue>ABCResource</AttributeValue>\n" +
        "        </Attribute>\n" +
        "    </Resource>\n" +
        "    <Subject>\n" +
        "        <Attribute AttributeId=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id\"\n" +
        "                   DataType=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string\">\n" +
        "            <AttributeValue>admin</AttributeValue>\n" +
        "        </Attribute>\n" +
        "        <Attribute AttributeId=\"http://wso2.org/claims/role\"\n" +
        "                   DataType=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string\">\n" +
        "            <AttributeValue>admin</AttributeValue>\n" +
        "        </Attribute>\n" +
        "    </Subject>\n" +
        "    <Action>\n" +
        "        <Attribute AttributeId=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id\"\n" +
        "                   DataType=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string\">\n" +
        "            <AttributeValue>read</AttributeValue>\n" +
        "        </Attribute>\n" +
        "    </Action>\n" +
        "    <Environment/>\n" +
        "</Request>";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        //set trust store properties required in SSL communication.
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
                "/home/pushpalanka/Servers/wso2is-4.1.1/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");

        //initialize authentication admin stub
        EntitlementClient remoteEntitlementClient = new EntitlementClient();
        //login using authentication admin stub providing valid credentials
        remoteEntitlementClient.login("admin", "admin");
        //initialize entitlement service stub with obtained authentication cookie
        remoteEntitlementClient.initEntitlementClient();
        //invoke EntitlementService by passing the XACML request and obtain the authorization decision
        String decision = entitlementServiceClient.getDecision(sampleRequest);
        //print the authorization decision
        System.out.println(decision);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}

public EntitlementClient() {
    try {
        ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, null);
        String authEPR = serverUrl + "AuthenticationAdmin";
        authstub = new AuthenticationAdminStub(ctx, authEPR);
        ServiceClient client = authstub._getServiceClient();
        Options options = client.getOptions();
        options.setManageSession(true);
        options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING, authCookie);
    } catch (AxisFault axisFault) {
        axisFault.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String login(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    //String cookie = null;
    boolean loggedIn = authstub.login(username, password, "127.0.0.1");
    if (loggedIn) {
        System.out.println("The user " + username + " logged in successfully.");
        authCookie = (String) authstub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext().getProperty(
                HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error logging in " + username);
    }
    return authCookie;
}

public void initEntitlementClient() throws AxisFault {
    entitlementServiceClient = new EntitlementServiceClient(authCookie, serverUrl, ctx);
}
```

}

Reference - http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2011/12/entitlement-service-xacml-pdp-as-web.html